# Automate creating custom configurations for Xcode subprojects

Tags: xcode, configuration, cocoapods

I'm trying to split my Xcode project into smaller modules and put related codes into separate modules (subprojects) in the same workspace and add target dependencies. My current project has several configurations, e.i. (Appstore, staging, production). Due to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39480195/1450348), the subprojects are required to have the exact configurations as my project. I was wondering if there's any way to automate this process.

I'm thinking about writing it myself or dig into cocoapods and find how it's done there to use that part, but was wondering if anybody else has had this issue and if there's a simple tool to do this

PS: [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30884779/1450348) might work, but since I'm using cocoapods for some dependencies, can't try it as cocoapods auto-generate the configs in dependency targets.